# Run SQL script on the server from within SQL developer on the client?

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper, sql-scripts

I am trying to create a pluggable database and am executing commands through sqldeveloper.

For enabling the 32k varchar support I need to run the script "@?/rdbms/admin/utl32k.sql;"..This script is present in the oracle database server. But my sqldeveloper is installed on a different machine..Is there any way to tell sqldeveloper that the path is relative to the server path and should be executed within the server ?

Comment: why not just login to the server locally and run from there, or copy the files to your local workstation.  just use sqlplus, no need for sqldeveloper.

Comment: Thats doable..I was just wondering if its possible to do from the client side..

Comment: Sure, if your server can map a network share.

Answer (score 0):

When running scripts in SQL Developer, there's no context or reference of any files on the database server itself.

So to run from a client connected to your database, a file on the db server...you would have to have a mapped drive or something similar.

So on your Windows/Mac, map a drive to the oracle db server as say F:, and then in your worksheet, you'd execute @f:/.../script.sql

What you REALLY should be doing though, is SSHing into the database server, and from a terminal, run SQL*Plus as SYS to execute that script.